# Assign files in a list when using the bash find command

Tags: bash, file

Im trying to see if I can assign the output of the `find` command to a variable. In this case it would be a list and iterate one file at a time to evaluate the file.

Ive tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/Users/mike/test

LIST='find $PATH -name *.txt'
for newfiles in @LIST; do
    #checksize
    echo $newfiles 
done
```

My output is:
`@LIST`

Im trying to do the same this as the glob command in perl in bash.

```
var = glob "PATH/*.txt";
```

Comment: Don't use `PATH` as a variable name; it already has a specific meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(command)` to execute `command` and substitute its output in place of that construct.

```
list=$(find "$PATH" -name '*.txt')
```

And to access a variable, put `$` before the name, not `@` (your `perl` experience is showing).

```
for newfiles in $list; do
    echo "$newfiles"
done
```

However, it's dangerous to parse the output of `find` like this, because you'll get incorrect results if any of the filenames contain whitespace -- it will be treated as multiple names. It's better to pipe the output:

```
find "$PATH" -name '*.txt' | while read -r newfiles; do
    echo "$newfiles"
done
```

Also, notice that you should quote any variables that you don't want to be split into multiple words if they contain whitespace.

And avoid using all-uppercase variable names. This is conventionally reserved for environment variables.

Comment: I dont have any whitespaces for the files being searched. We try to avoid it. But to pipe the output looks much nicer and cleaner. This word perfectly thanks for the pointers

Comment: It's best to write defensive code. Maybe someone will add a file like that by mistake, then your scripts will fail.

Comment: To be fully defensive, you also need to account for file names containing newlines.

Comment: Another reason why I wanted the files in a list is because I wanted to validate them first before doing anything with them. Like check the size and swap if they are ok. I think the while loop just checks one at a time. If one of them is invalid I need to abort and not do anywork

Answer (score 1):

LIST=$(find $PATH -name *.txt)
   for newfiles in $LIST; do

Beware that you will have issues if any of the files have whitespace in the names.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `bash` 4 or later, don't use `find` at all here.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
list=( "$path"/**/*.txt )
for newfile in "${list[@]}"; do
    echo "$newfile"
done
```